# Further Optimizations of Higher Order Recursive Functions to Iterative Forms

Tags: c#, higher-order-functions

I am attempting to optimize the following two recursive functions. My thoughts are to convert the following 2 functions from Recursive to Iterative forms.

The First:

```
    public static long SumNPFI(long n, Func<long, bool> p, Func<long, long> f, Func<long, long> inc)
    {
        /// <summary>Returns the value of longeger n if the predicate is satisfied,
        /// otherwise it returns the following sum: f(n) + f(inc(n)) + f(inc(inc(n))) ... 
        /// until the argument of f satisfies the predicate
        /// </summary>
        if (p(n))
        {
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            return f(n) + SumNPFI(inc(n), p, f, inc);
        };
    }
```

And the Second:

```
    public static long ComposeNPF(long n, Func<long, bool> p, Func<long, long> f)
    {
        /// <summary>Returns the value f(n) if the predicate is satisfied,
        /// otherwise it returns: f(f(f(...f(n)...))) until this satisfies the predicate. 
        /// </summary>
        
        if ((p(f(n))))
        {
            return f(n);
        }

        return ComposeNPF(f(n), p, f);
    }
```

So here I have used while loops to convert these functions to iterative forms:

The First:

```
    public static long SumNPFI_While(long n, Func<long, bool> p, Func<long, long> f, Func<long, long> inc)
    {
        /// <summary>Returns the value of longeger n if the predicate is satisfied,
        /// otherwise it returns the following sum: f(n) + f(inc(n)) + f(inc(inc(n))) ... 
        /// until the argument of f satisfies the predicate
        /// </summary>
        long result = 0;
        while (!p(n))
        {
            result += f(n);
            n = inc(n);
        }
        return result + n;
    }
```

The Second:

```
    public static long ComposeNPF_While(long n, Func<long, bool> p, Func<long, long> f)
    {
        /// <summary>Returns the value f(n) if the predicate is satisfied,
        /// otherwise it returns: f(f(f(...f(n)...))) until this satisfies the predicate. 
        /// </summary>

        long result = f(n);
        while (!p(result))
        {
            result = f(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Which is great, these are iterative, but they still aren't optimized enough for what I need, does anybody have any ideas of how this could be done?

An example usage case could be to use these Functions to perform DigitalSum of a number for example:

DigitalSum(3) = 3

DigitalSum(36) = 9

DigitalSum(361) = 1

The final DigitalSum is 1 because 361 -> 10 -> 1 for example.

Here is the implementation using the 2 higher order functions above!

```
    private static bool Between0And10(long n) => 0 < n && n < 10;
    private static long Increment(long n) => n / 10;
    public static long LastDigit(long n) => n % 10;
    public static long SumDigits(long n) => SumNPFI(n, Between0And10, LastDigit, Increment);
    public static long DigitalSum(long n) => ComposeNPF(n, Between0And10, SumDigits);
```

The motivation behind all of this, is the higher order functions themselves I think could be useful abstractions but they just aren't quick enough to justify using them at the moment.

Comment: I should add that I have tried using the looping mechanisms available in C# but these don't seem to work.

Comment: Can you share your attempts to use looping in C#?  That turns the problem into "help me find the error in my code" which is better received here than "please do this work for me."

Comment: Yeah sure no problem! I'll get that done as soon as I can.

Comment: And what problem(s) do you have with your solutions?  You need to have some *specific* problem to solve for the question to be suitable for this site.

Comment: You can calculate DigitalSum with these abstractions for example ^^^